# Two way wiring using SSR

Tags: relay, wiring, solid-state-relay, switching

I am working on a IOT application and I want to control a switch as per two way wiring using SSR.

I have made it with Relay which is having two NO NC contact but I wonder how will it possible with SSR.

Two way wiring diagram is as follows.

[image]

With SSR I can't have this

[image]

Any help would  be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Abhishek - are we done now? Can this question be closed-down as "answered" or, do you still need more information or help?

Answer (score 2):

Think a little bit out of the box. You have two independent signals that each want to invert the action of the other - that's how a two way light switch works and, importantly, that is how an exclusive OR gate works.

So, whatever form your two independent signals take - make them logic compatible and feed them into an exclusive OR gate then, with an appropriate transistor, stage drive the SSR. When you said: -

> *With SSR I can't have this*

I have to disagree because the "clever" logic is on the input side.